# R - melt and ggplot2 how to aggregate

Tags: r, reshape2

I'm trying to understand how `melt` in the package `reshape2` can help me plot my dataset. Currenly my dataset looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(factor1 = c("a","a","c","d","e"), factor2 = c("a1","a1","b1","a1","b1"),
                 factor3 = c("a2","b2","c2","d2","e2"), factor4 = c("a3","b3","c3","d3","e3"))
df$values <- abs(rnorm(5))

test <- melt(df, id.vars = c('factor1', 'factor2'), measure.vars = "values")
test


ggplot(test, mapping= aes(x=as.factor(`factor1`), y = value)) + 
  geom_line(group=1) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label= round(value,2))) +
  facet_grid(`factor2` ~ .) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x,"%")) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 20,hjust=1))
```

[image]

Now as seen from the graph, the value under the first facet is repeated twice, for 0.1 and 0.06, and this is because factor 3 and 4 both have different values but the same factor1 and factor2 value.

My question is how can I get it to aggregate over what I choose it should facet by? I.e. I want the duplicate point to be shown as 0.1 + 0.06, without using some sort of aggregate function? The reason I don't want to use an aggregate function is because there's many factors in my data and I want to be able to plot without first aggregating the data many times. Is this possuible?

Comment: to clarify you literally want the point to be labelled with "0.1 + 0.06"? Or did you mean "0.16"? If the latter, I'm afraid you will have to go through steps of aggregating (I'm guessing it'll add at most 5 to 10 lines of code via `group_by` `summarise` with `library(dplyr)`).

Comment: @Yes 0.16 - ok i'll just go through that, I was just wondering if there was a better way